# Should I reauthenticate user again after updating user's profile? Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I created login feature with Firebase Authentication and stored user registered on firebase realtime database. When I edited profile, the database and authentication has been successful updated on the tables but the problem I've found is the application. The application asked the user to reauthenticate the account after updating the profile. The logic flow is when user update profile on edit profile menu,  the data should stored to firebase and then, intent to profile page.

There are codes, I've tried.

Edit Profile Class Java

```
package co.id.roni.usertestapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class EditProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView photoEditProfile;
    EditText namaEditProfile, passwordEditProfile, emailEditProfile;
    ImageButton btnSaveImageProfile;

    Uri photo_location;
    Integer photo_max = 1;

    DatabaseReference referenceEdit;
    StorageReference storageEdit;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuthEdit;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUserEdit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);
        Button btnSaveEditProfile = findViewById(R.id.btn_save_edit);
        btnSaveImageProfile = findViewById(R.id.img_btn_upload_new_photo);
        btnSaveEditProfile.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSaveImageProfile.setOnClickListener(this);

        photoEditProfile = findViewById(R.id.img_profil_edit);
        namaEditProfile = findViewById(R.id.edit_nama);
        emailEditProfile = findViewById(R.id.edt_email_profile);
        passwordEditProfile = findViewById(R.id.edt_pass_profile);

        firebaseAuthEdit = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUserEdit = firebaseAuthEdit.getCurrentUser();
        referenceEdit = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(firebaseUserEdit.getUid());
        storageEdit = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("PhotoUsers").child(firebaseUserEdit.getUid());

        referenceEdit.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                namaEditProfile.setText(dataSnapshot.child("nama").getValue().toString());
                emailEditProfile.setText(dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString());
                passwordEditProfile.setText(dataSnapshot.child("pass").getValue().toString());
                Picasso.get().load(dataSnapshot.child("url_photo_user").getValue().toString()).into(photoEditProfile);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_save_edit) {
            saveEditProfile();
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.img_btn_upload_new_photo) {
            findPhoto();
        }
    }

    private void saveEditProfile() {
        final String email = emailEditProfile.getText().toString();
        final String pass = passwordEditProfile.getText().toString();

        firebaseUserEdit.updateEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    referenceEdit.getRef().child("email").setValue(emailEditProfile.getText().toString());
                }
                else{
                    Log.d("Pesan Error", "Gagal Update : "+task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
        firebaseUserEdit.updatePassword(pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    referenceEdit.getRef().child("pass").setValue(passwordEditProfile.getText().toString());
                }
                else{
                    Log.d("Pesan Error", "Gagal Update : "+task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
        referenceEdit.getRef().child("nama").setValue(namaEditProfile.getText().toString());
        if (photo_location != null) {
            StorageReference storageReference1 = storageEdit.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(photo_location));
            storageReference1.putFile(photo_location).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Task<Uri> task = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();
                    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            String uri_photo = uri.toString();
                            referenceEdit.getRef().child("url_photo_user").setValue(uri_photo);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    //pindah ke Profile
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("userId", firebaseUserEdit.getUid());
                    startActivity(new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this, ProfilUserActivity.class).putExtras(bundle));

                }
            });
        }
    }

    String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
    }

    public void findPhoto() {
        Intent pic = new Intent();
        pic.setType("image/*");
        pic.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(pic, photo_max);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == photo_max && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            photo_location = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(photo_location).centerCrop().fit().into(photoEditProfile);
        }
    }
}
```

Profil Page Class Java

```
package co.id.roni.usertestapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class ProfilUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView namaProfile, emailProfile;
    ImageView photoImageProfile;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuthMain;
    FirebaseUser user;
    DatabaseReference profileDb;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profil_user);
        Button btnEditProfile = findViewById(R.id.btn_edit_profile);
        Button btnSignOut = findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
        namaProfile = findViewById(R.id.tv_nama_profil);
        emailProfile = findViewById(R.id.tv_email_profil_page);
        photoImageProfile = findViewById(R.id.img_profile_page);

        firebaseAuthMain = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = firebaseAuthMain.getCurrentUser();

        showProfile();

        btnEditProfile.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void showProfile() {
        profileDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid());
        profileDb.getRef().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                namaProfile.setText(dataSnapshot.child("nama").getValue().toString());
                emailProfile.setText(dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString());
                Picasso.get().load(dataSnapshot.child("url_photo_user").getValue().toString()).centerCrop().fit().into(photoImageProfile);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e("Pesan", "Gagal Load"+databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.btn_edit_profile){
            startActivity(new Intent(ProfilUserActivity.this, EditProfileActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
        if(view.getId() == R.id.btn_sign_out){
            startActivity(new Intent(ProfilUserActivity.this, UserMainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

    }
}
```

I expected the result is the application can intent to Profil Page after updating profile. I would like to appreciate to help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `startActivityForResult`. Using activity result you can pass updated user object back to profile activity from edit profile activity, and can update data.

Comment: Oke, I will tried, Thanks